# Getting value of hidden for by the div tag id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id = "abc1">
<input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_0_the" value = 314/>
<input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_1_the" value = 315/>
</div><div id = "abc2">
<input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_0_the" value = 316/>
<input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_1_the" value = 317/>
</div>
```

Now I need to get the value present in input tag by using the JavaScript
as I need to send the value to controller by ajax call. I have tried below which is giving undefined.

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('#abc1 > aabc_0_the').value
```

Each div is a partial view

Comment: You should not have same id for two different input. use class instead.

Comment: As you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id, _The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be **unique** in the whole document_. That being said you shouldn't use the same id for the two hidden fields you have in your HTML.

Comment: and your  selector is not looking for an id

Answer (score 1):

ID is unique so you should change id or use classes.

```
<div id = "abc1">
    <input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_0_the" value = "314"/>
</div>
<div id = "abc2">
    <input type = "hidden" id= "aabc_1_the" value = "315"/>
</div>
```

Using javascript :

```
var value=document.getElementById('aabc_0_the').value;
var value1=document.getElementById('aabc_1_the').value;
```

In jQuery :

```
var value = $('#aabc_0_the').val();
var value1 = $('#aabc_1_the').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't duplicate id.

In JS

```
var value=document.body.getElementById('aabc_0_the').value();
```

In JQuery

```
    var value=$('#aabc_0_the').val();


<div id = "abc1">
<input type = "hidden" class= "aabc_0_the" value = 314/>
</div><div id = "abc2">
<input type = "hidden" class= "aabc_0_the" value = 315/>
</div>


var v1=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the:eq(0)').val();
var v2=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the:eq(1)').val();

or

var v1=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the').first().val();
var v1=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the').last().val();

or

var v1=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the:first').val();
var v1=$('#abc1 .aabc_0_the:last').val();
```

Comment: ?? im dont understand

Comment: Heh. In English, that says "would it be possible for you not to use txtspk, thanks". See my edit - we prefer contributions here to be written in a professional and technical style. Stack Overflow is not Facebook `:-)`

Comment: well i will try it.
as this not exactly it looks, i have a partial view which is diplayed twice in a single page. so just to stop any confusion i have given like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var value_one = $('#abc1').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    var value_two = $('#abc2').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    console.log(value_one, value_two);
});
```